# How do I check if a key inside a hash exists (redis)?

Tags: javascript, redis, node-redis

How do I check if a key inside a hash exists (redis)?

I tried this way:

```
redisClient.exists(obj.mydict.user.toString().pos, function(err,reply) {
                if(!err) {
                    if(reply !== null) {
                    ...
```

however I get:

```
node_redis: Deprecated: The EXISTS command contains a "undefined" argument.
This is converted to a "undefined" string now and will return an error from v.3.0 on.
Please handle this in your code to make sure everything works as you intended it to.
```

I do not know how. What I'm trying is to check if my **.pos** key exists in my hash **obj.mydict.user.toString()**, how would it do it in *node_redis*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using in?

```
var hash = {'a': 1, 'b': 2};
console.log('a' in hash);
console.log('c' in hash);
```

Comment: so, this way I did, but then I'll have to search for all hash in redis, I just want to check if there is a key in the bank.

Comment: from what I see in the documentation here, it does not seem to have. So the way is: `redisClient.hgetall(obj.mydict.user.toString(),function(err,reply) { if(!err) {if("pos" in reply){ ...`

Answer (score 2):

While there is no specific command to check for field existence in a Redis Hash, you can call [`HGET`](https://redis.io/commands/hget) and deduce non-existence from `nil` replies.

Answer (score 0):

```
   // you can use 'hget' to check the existence of your key in particular hash like as follow:

client.hget('HASH NAME', 'mykey',function(err, result) 
        {
             if(err)
              console.log(err.message);
             console.log(JSON.stringify(result)); 

        });
```